# sublime shortcut for erb comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sublimetext2

In sublime command + / is not working for me to comment out erb and also can't block comment out erb + html, does anyone know how to fix this, maybe a package?

For example, I want to comment out this code in sublime:

```
1 <% post.categories.each do |category| %>
2   <%= category.name %>
3 <% end %>
```

I can not just "command + /" or "command+option+/" for the selection because either of those only puts a regular style html comment around the selection. If I try commenting out just line one with command + / it puts a pound symbol # before the line - a ruby comment, not erb.

Instead to comment it out I will have to put a pound sign in the first line, then put a pound sign in the second line and an html comment around it, then put a pound sign in the third line.

So finally it will look like this

```
<%# post.categories.each do |category| %>
<!-- <%#= category.name %> -->
<%# end %>
```

I have HTML(Rails) selected.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you followed the steps at this [github](https://github.com/mhartl/rails_tutorial_sublime_text) link given in [rails](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) tutorial.
package installing and editing the keys are clearly explained there.

Answer (score 2):

using [SublimeERB plugin](https://github.com/eddorre/SublimeERB) you can toggle between different erb tag modes including comment style.

[image]

Comment: This is nice, but its not exactly what I'm looking for. I need a way to comment blocks of text quickly that have already been written with the same functionality as command+/.